# What is unknown construction in class declaration?

Tags: c#, syntax

I've just made a mistake while writing my code, and I find out some interesting unknown stuff.

```
public class OperationFactory(int code)
{
}
```

What `(int code)` it is here?

My compiler doesn't tell anything, so that's why I'm asking

[image]

Comment: It's invalid c#, your compiler should complain, doesn't it?

Comment: If you want to declare a constructor with a parameter `int code`, you have to declare it _inside_ the class, not at the class declaration itself.

Comment: @RenéVogt It's a valid class declaration, my compiler doesn't tell me anything, so, that's why I'm asking

Comment: @Asura Are you sure you actually compiled? That code is simply not a valid syntax. No compiler would accept that.

Comment: Please post code as text, not as image. So it's easier for others to search and copy it to reproduce the issue. Btw: your compiler seems broken, mine is complaining with cs0116 and cs1022. It is **not** valid c#.

Comment: Some old (preview) compiler by any chance? Sounds like the removed 'primary constructors' feature, although its odd that it works for static classes. Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2014/october/csharp-the-new-and-improved-csharp-6-0#primary-constructors

Comment: There is a proposal for automatic implemented properties: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/14853 but as far as I know, it has no implemented in any c# version yet.

Comment: What are your VS version and .Net target (core 2, 3, framework 4.7, 4.8)? Also, cannot reproduce, my compiler complains about it.

Comment: @Asura , that is not a valid declaration of class,any compiler will not accept it.

Answer (score 2):

I hope that You are not using Visual Studio IDE. are you?
I thought you are using Visual studio Code, need to install c# intelligence extensions if using other IDE's.

> Compilation error. You may see warning if you are using Visual Studio IDE.

The Definition of class not allowing to take parameters [msdn link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/classes)

```
//[access modifier] - [class] - [identifier]
public class Customer
{
   // Fields, properties, methods and events go here...
}
```